# swift iOS add CIFilter to video in realtime using moviefileoutput

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, cifilter, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am trying to swipe through CIFilters to apply to my live video camera, however I am using movieFileOutput & the examples I have seen utilize videoDataOutput. Is it possible to merely create a subview of imageView on my previewView? Or does it require more than that to get the filter I desire? Also code is is swift 2 just to clarify

Comment: Did you ever find out? Have the same question!

Comment: yes @DavidH I used pod found here : [SCRecorder] (https://cocoapods.org/?q=screcord)